# Jquery get next specific tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html code like this:

```
<div id="sd">
<p article="start" a_type="advertisement" cid="dsfd"></p>
<p article="start" a_type="nope" cid="vvb"></p>
<page_number>106</page_number>
</div>
```

so if use `$("#sd").each` and when Im in first p tag ( `<p article="start" a_type="advertisement" cid="dsfd"></p>`) i cant use  `$(this).next("page_number").html();`
It always show as undefined.

```
$("#sd").each(function(){

 sd = $(this).next("page_number").html();
 alert(sd);

});
```

but result shows:

```
undefined //fist alert
 106 //second alert
```

i want result  like:

```
 106 //fist alert
 106 //second alert
```

second question is:

I have a html code like that:

```
<div id="sd">
    <dc_title article="start" cid="#P1_001"></dc_title>
    <p article_con="1.1" cid="#P1_013"></p>
    <p article="start" cid="#P2_001"></p>
    <p article_con="2.1" cid="#P2_004"></p>
    <p article_con="2.1" cid="#P3_001"></p>
    <p article_con="2.1" cid="#P3_005"></p>
    <p article_con="2.1" cid="#P4_001"></p>
    <p article="end" cid="#P4_002"></p>
    <img article_con="1.1" cid="#P5_040">
    <pam_credit article="end" cid="#P5_043"></pam_credit>
    <dc_title article="start" cid="#P14_001"></dc_title>
    <p article_con="14.1" cid="#P14_040"></p>
    <p article_con="14.1" cid="#P16_005"></p>
    <p article="end" cid="#P16_018"></p>
    <prism_object article="start" cid="#P20_001"></prism_object>
    <p article_con="20.1" cid="#P20_009"></p>
    <p article_con="20.1" cid="#P21_001"></p>
    <p article="end" cid="#P21_004"></p>
    <dc_title article="start" cid="#P22_001"></dc_title>
    <pam_caption article_con="22.1" cid="#P22_017"></pam_caption>
    <p article_con="22.1" cid="#P23_001"></p>
    <dc_creator article="end" cid="#P23_007"></dc_creator>
    <dc_title article="start" cid="#P23_018"></dc_title>
    <p article_con="23.1" cid="#P23_027"></p>
    <pq_subtitle article_con="23.1" cid="#P25_016"></pq_subtitle>
    <p article="end" cid="#P25_023"></p>
</div>
```

so i want to find pattern more than one like this:

```
<p article="start" cid="#P1_001"></dc_title>
<p article_con="1.1" cid="#P1_013"></p>
```

dont mind the tag name but `article="start" article_con=` and article_con must be same.for example

in some place there's tag like this:

```
<p article="start" cid="#P1_001"></dc_title>
<p article_con="1.1" cid="#P1_013"></p>
```

and anther place same same tag like that:

```
<p article="start" cid="#P1_001"></dc_title>
<p article_con="1.1" cid="#P1_013"></p>
```

but it doesn't matter

```
<p article="start" cid="#P1_001"></dc_title>
<p article_con="1.1" cid="#P1_013"></p>
```

and anther place same same tag like that:

```
<p article="start" cid="#P1_001"></dc_title>
<p article_con="2.1" cid="#P1_013"></p>
```

Comment: You realize you're making up all kinds of tags and attributes, right? The question itself is a bit muddled, but if you want to get the next element of a certain tag name (or any other selector), use [`$(this).nextAll('tagname').get(0)`](http://jsfiddle.net/hwf6pyyu/) (`this` being a reference to which element you're working from, it could be a selector instead).

Comment: thanks, it worked, answer the question, ill mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the next element of a certain tag name (or any other selector), use:

```
$(this).nextAll('tagname').get(0)
```

`this` being a reference to which element you're working from, it could be a selector instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/hwf6pyyu/

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, the 'page_number' element is the child of 'sd' div, you should use:

```
$("#sd").children().each(function(){ ...
```